To address the issue of the microphone picking up both the user's voice and the NVDA (Nonvisual Desktop Access) voice output while recording
I have implemented a voice-to-text feature in my application, and I am utilizing the connected earphone microphone for voice input using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}) API. The accessibility tool NVDA is also running in the background. Now, the issue I am facing is that the microphone is picking up the NVDA (Nonvisual Desktop Access) voice output along with the user's voice while I am recording with the microphone. Since NVDA provides auditory feedback, it is being captured by the microphone along with the user's voice input, resulting in interference.
I am expecting only user voice to be recorded while filtering out voice output from accessibility tool (for ex: NVDA).
I tried to solve the problem using the deviceId property in Angular.
Here is the sample code:
  const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  const microphone = devices.find(device =\> device.kind === 'audioinput');
  if (microphone) {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: { deviceId: {exact:
  microphone.deviceId}}});
  // Use the obtained stream for recording
  } else {
  console.error('Microphone not found');
  }


This is probably more an hardware than a software problem.
Some computers have a noise reduction option and/or have filters to automatically disregard audio feedback coming from their own speakers.
Such filters can automatically applied on audio output when the microphone become active, but you have no control on that for your own app or from a browser. You need to go to the control panel or a specific manifacturer app to configure that.
So if your computer hasn't anything of that sort, the best is probably to use headphones, external mic and/or speakers or an external soundcard providing such features.
